# API data send from PHP to JS

Tags: javascript, php

I have been dealing with the problem that I can not fetch the API data from `json_encode`, it returns html file or it gives the error if I change the code a little bit:

> "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON"

and I don't understand why. Could anyone help?

controller.php

```
<?php  
if(empty($_POST['page'])){
 include('include/mainpage.php');
  exit();
}

require('include/model.php');
if($_POST['page']=='mainpage'){
    include('include/mainpage.php');
  }


if($_POST['command']=='city'){
      $api= get_api();
      //json object
      echo json_encode($api);
}
?>
```

model.php

```
<?php

function get_api(){
if(isset($_POST['cityname'])){
  $city= $_POST['cityname'];
  $api_key= "25a8988cc514c4753be58564848636a0";
  $api= "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$city&appid=$api_key";
  $api_data= file_get_contents($api);
  
}
else{
    $api_data=null; 
}
return $api_data;
 }
 ?>
```

mainpage.php

```
 <script>

fetch('controller.php')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => console.log(JSON.stringify(json)))
  </script>
```

Comment: This occurs when the API doesn’t return JSON in its document body, such as due to a 404, here an HTML document is returned. In this case, it expects to find a`{` (start of JSON); instead it finds a `<` (start of a heading element). Check the returned data in the console to get what's going on.

Comment: I figured it out. I create a data.json file by using file_put_contents and using fetch to access data.json file

Comment: While that is a possible solution, you shouldn't need to do it like that. You can make PHP output JSON only, without any HTML before or after it. Usually it's better if the PHP code which handles fetch() requests and returns JSON is in a separate file than code which outputs HTML, then it's easier not to make a mess of the output.